# after updating PHP to 7.4 my BarcodeGeneratorHTML crashed | Laravel,PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, deprecated, php-7.4

i used to use my Laravel Project with PhP 5.6 and i'm using barcode Gnerator for my project some where and to do this i use this package .

```
laravel/laravel barcode_blog
```

now i upgraded my PhP To 7.4 (note: didn't upgrade my laravel yet).
everything is working fine just when i search for a spasific barcode i got this error :

```
ErrorException in BarcodeGenerator.php line 293: 
Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated (View:.../.../..)
```

now this is the code :

```html
<tr>
    <td width="19%">serial NUM</td>
    <td style="width: 1%">:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
     @if (!empty($INSTANCE))
       <?php $generator = new \Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorHTML(); ?>
       {!! $generator->getBarcode($INSTANCE->barcode, $generator::TYPE_CODE_128) !!}
    @endif
    </td>
   </tr>
```

And I know the problem is with  $generator = new \Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorHTML(); this line when i delete it my code is working fine but i need it in the code how to use it in php 7.4 i belive it get changed

Comment: Try composer update

Answer (score 1):

Update your composer or to be exact, update picqer/php-barcode-generator version and it will work fine. To update composer, just type
'composer update' on the terminal within your project files and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Installing packages via composer installs packages based on your environment (PHP version).

This means that if you upgrade your PHP version you have to update your installed packages as well via `composer update` as mentioned before.

But your versions in composer.json might be locked to some specific versions, in which case you will have to change that as well.
Composer update will leave you an error message then.

What I usual do is:

- Try running `composer update`
- If it fails or syntax errors still occur in the project I look up the package on packagist.org to see what major versions require what PHP versions
  [image: Screenshot from Packagist.org regarding versions]
- Packages on packagist usually adher to the semantic versioning ([semver.org](https://semver.org)) which means that you would typically have to find a new major version (the first number in versioning) that can run on your PHP version.

In your example you should be able to change the `picqer/php-barcode-generator` package to use version `2.1` or higher.

Comment: i did that and i got another error :

Comment: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGenerator::getBarcodeData() must be of the type string, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\....\vendor\picqer\php-barcode-generator\src\BarcodeGeneratorHTML.php on line 20

Comment: You pass `null` into the getBarcodeData() method, but that is not allowed. Please see example here: https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator#usage

Comment: no im passing this $INSTANCE->barcode shouldn't be null it was working before

Comment: It is indeed null. The error message states it clearly. You will have to dig a bit deeper for debugging. Try to var_dump() the variable right before calling the getBarcodeData().

Comment: oh thanks its working now i just wrap it inside if(!is_null($INSTANCE->barcode))

Answer (score 0):

downgrade the php version on your server e.g from 8.0 to 7.4 solved it for me